# How do I install Big Sur from a USB without having to change settings in Startup Security Utility

Tags: disk-utility, usb, security, big-sur, bootable-disk

I sold my old Air on eBay and the customer returned it with "fakesoftware" as the username.

I ended up keeping both the Mac and the money because this user was a scammer of some sort.

Anyway, I wanted to reinstall Big Sur on it from usb, so I followed this:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372

I have it all setup, but I can't run from an external drive without changing it in startup security utility which is requesting I "Enter macOS Password" for "User: fakesoftware", which I obviously don't want to do...

What is the approach I just want to wipe and start fresh with Big Sur with someone's "fake software" already on this which could be doing god knows what.